# How to create table dynamically using JSTL?I Have MAP(ArrayList<MODEL> ) Object in SpringFramework

Tags: java, spring, jstl

How to create table dynamically using JSTL?

I Have MAP(ArrayList ) Object in SpringFramework

```
  Map<String, ArrayList<TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel>> makeobjmap=new HashMap<String, ArrayList<TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel>>();
```

===>This map's value is this ↓↓↓↓↓↓

```
totalal3=[TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=0, dormId=3, dormName=Adorm, taxName=電気, taxFee=未登録],
 TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=0, dormId=3, dormName=Adorm, taxName=インタネット, taxFee=未登録], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=0, dormId=3, dormName=Adorm, taxName=水道, taxFee=未登録], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=0, dormId=3, dormName=Adorm, taxName=ガス, taxFee=未登録]], 

totalal2=[TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=2, dormId=2, dormName=Bdorm, taxName=電気, taxFee=4000], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=4, dormId=2, dormName=Bdorm, taxName=インタネット, taxFee=3000], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=6, dormId=2, dormName=Bdorm, taxName=水道, taxFee=3000], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=0, dormId=2, dormName=Bdorm, taxName=ガス, taxFee=未登録]],

 totalal1=[TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=1, dormId=1, dormName=Cdorm, taxName=電気, taxFee=3000], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=3, dormId=1, dormName=Cdorm, taxName=インタネット, taxFee=2500], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=5, dormId=1, dormName=Cdorm, taxName=水道, taxFee=3000], 
TaxAllTotalChargeViewModel [taxDetailId=7, dormId=1, dormName=Cdorm, taxName=ガス, taxFee=3000]]}
```

I want to Transpose vertical to Horizontal and each categories can change dynamically So I tried to make modelObject mappinged by Table's each 
and I put tham in Map. 
Why did I use Map<> interface, I need make variable and Object in Java.

I want to make this form.

```
  <!--   ★ This is what I want result through this logic

    <tr>
            <td>chargeMonth</td>
            <td>dormitoryName</td>　
            <td>tax1_fee<i class="fa fa-trash-o "  aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td>tax2_fee  <i class="fa fa-trash-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
            <td>tax3_fee</td>
    ....(category can increase or decrease)
            </tr>
    <br>
    <tr>
                <br><td>９</td>
                <td>dorm_A</td>　
                <td>1500  <i class="fa fa-trash-o "  aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td>1500  <i class="fa fa-trash-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td>2500  <i class="fa fa-trash-o " aria-hidden="true"></i>  <i class="fa fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>
                <td>not exist</td>
                </tr>
    -->
```

★  each cycle is one td tag  :) I have to add close tr tag when prepared  every td value in tr row.

```
    <c:forEach items="${makeobjmap}" var="makeobjmap">
      <c:forEach items="${makeobjmap.value}" var="totallist ">
        <c:forEach items="${totallist}" var ="totalmodel" varStatus="status">
    <c:if test="status.first">   
           <tr>
                <td>${month}</td>
                 <td>${totalmodel.dormName}</td>
           </c:if>
            <td>${totalmodel.taxFee}
       </td>
        <c:if test="status.last">
             </tr>
        </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:forEach> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

but All data is displayed in one line and 
repeat 12time... :(
and I think  and ${status.first} is not a function
how can I fixed it?

Comment: why did you put </tr> inside <c:if ?

Comment: I have to change row when for each one cycle after

Comment: try changing <c:if test="status.last">
                                                 </tr>
    </c:if> to <c:if test="status.last">
    </c:if>     </tr>

Comment: thank you very much jobin! but i can't  because each cycle is one <td> </td> :)  I have to add </tr> tag when prepared every <td> value in <tr> row.

Comment: try isLast() instead of last